# What does this mean "index is also maintained in the transaction log"?

Tags: sql-server, index, transaction-log

"Index is also maintained in the transaction log"

Does this mean when a table having an index is queried, the entire index is pulled into the memory and subsequently logged into tlog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, querying things does not write data to the [transaction log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). The transaction log is the log of changes to your database.

When you update an indexed column, the index is updated. The changes this makes to the index are logged in the transaction log the same way that the changes made to the table are logged. This is because if your database was to crash, your indexes need to be recovered too.